# position: sticky jumps when selecting option

Tags: css, position, sticky

I'm trying to use the css style, position: sticky. It works great except for when the select element becomes active. The page scrolls back to the position of the sticky element.

```
<div style="position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; top: 0;">
    <select>
        <option>Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrxVoy

I couldn't find anything online that addressed this. Has anyone ran into this before and have a solution?

Thanks!

Browser: Chrome 67.0.3396.79

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium.

Sticky works as expected in Firefox.

Bug report found: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=805800#c9

Comment: Weirdly enough, it works fine on my firefox (win10 atm). What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Just checked Firefox and it's working for me as well.

Comment: And on safari it doesn't seem to work at all. Maybe you should make your own select with <div>'s

Comment: @GeorgiosDimitriadis: I've added -webkit-sticky to the codepen. It should work in Safari now.

Comment: try  postion:fixed instead

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @SaraKat. The element should only be fixed when the user scrolls past it though. I was originally using some js to toggle the fixed state but would like to use position sticky instead.

Comment: @Josh now that you are saying it , I think that it is because of chrome , I always experienced that when using wordpress templates with sticky headers

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because it is applied to a form element. When you click on the element, the browser is programmed to go to the location of it if *it's base location* is off-screen. Firefox is programmed differently and only does this if the element *itself* is off-screen.

To fix it, try using `position:fixed;` instead. Since there isn't anything above the element there's no reason to use `sticky`.